# Get the exit code 1 if file is not empty

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file of name output.txt, If the file **output.txt** is not empty then I need to exit the script with exit code **1**.

I tried the below code but not getting the desired output:

```
#!/bin/bash
OUT=`cat output.txt`

if [ "$OUT" -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "The script ran ok"
  exit 0
else
  echo "The script failed"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You're testing the value of `$OUT`, not the length of it.

Comment: @Barmar How o test the length of the file output.txt

Comment: No need to `cat` the file to a var to test if it's empty or not: `if [ -s file ] ; then echo exit 1 ; else echo exit 0 ; fi` . `man bash`: _[ -s FILE ] True if FILE exists and has a size greater than zero._ You could also: `[[ ! -s file ]] ; echo $?`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-z` test to test if a string is empty.

```
if [ -z "$OUT" ]
```